# Printing a A4 Booklet on A3 paper using lpr command

Tags: lpr

I would like to print a A4 Booklet on A3 paper on my mac os.
For a strange reason only A5 booklet is produced.
Here the command I use:

```
lpr -o sides=two-sided-long-edge -o fit-to-page -o PageSize=A3 -o InputSlot=Tray3 -o Duplex=DuplexNoTumble -o XRFinishing=Booklet -o XRFoldOption=BookletFold -o XRBookletLayout=true -o XRBookletSize=A3 file.pdf
```

natural-scaling option seems to produce nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with this . The PageSize wan't correct (and I added also folding paper)

```
lpr -o sides=two-sided-long-edge -o fit-to-page  -o PageSize=A4 -o InputSlot=Tray3 -o Duplex=DuplexNoTumble -o XRFinishing=Booklet -o XRFoldOption=BookletFold -o XRBookletLayout=true -o XRBookletSize=A3 -o XRFoldOption=BookletFold
```